# How to refresh the specific Lightning component not the lightning page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, salesforce1-app, lightning-apps, lightning-experience

I have two lightning component placed on one page lightning app.
First Component have refresh icon and I set onclick action to refresh Component
**`$A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire();`** but this event refresh the whole page instead of First component.  how can refresh only one component on page not all the page ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you are refreshing the component from the context of a parent, you don't need to use an event - you can expose a `method` to the parent and get it to call that.

If you are refreshing the component from within the child itself, you could either use an event or re-run your `init` routine.

**So for a parent calling a public `method`:**

```
 <aura:method name="reInit" action="{!c.doInit}" description="Runs the init method again ">
```

The parent could get a reference to the child component and call `childComponent.reInit()`

For a parent totally refreshing the child, the parent could dynamically recreate the component:

```
    //clear body of host component just in case
var hostComponent = component.find("enclosingComponent");
hostComponent.set("v.body", []);

$A.createComponent(
  'c:YourChildComponent', {
          "someParam":"someValue"
  },
  function(newComponent, status, errorMessage) {
    //Add the new button to the body array
    if (status === "SUCCESS") {
      var body = hostComponent.get("v.body");
      body.push(newComponent);
      hostComponent.set("v.body", body);
    } else if (status === "INCOMPLETE") {
      console.log("No response from server or client is offline.");
    } else if (status === "ERROR") {
      console.log("Error: " + errorMessage);
    }
  }
);
```

**From the child component**
If you are doing this from within the component, you can despatch an event to the parent if you want a total refresh, or run the `reInit` method yourself.

You can define a new `COMPONENT` event fire it to tell the parent that you want to be refreshed.

```
<aura:event type="COMPONENT" description="Event used to tell the parent to refresh" >
  <aura:attribute name="componentName" type="string"/>
</aura:event>
```

In the child component:

```
<!--markup-->
<aura:registerEvent name="refreshChildComponent" type="c:RefreshChild"/>

//handler
var e = component.getEvent("refreshChildComponent");
e.setParams({ "componentName": "child1"});
e.fire();
```

In the parent component:

```
<aura:handler name="refreshChildComponent" event="c:RefreshChild" action="{!c.refreshChild}" />
```

In the parent helper, the same code as above could be called - in **the parent calling a public method** section

Answer (score 9):

You are not supposed to refresh one specific component, as the component firing the refresh is not supposed to know what other components are on the page. Instead, create and [fire your own event](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_application_fire.htm), and [handle it](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/events_application_handling.htm) in the components that needs to be refreshed.

Comment: @Faiben can you please give me the basic example because i did't get how to create own refresh event because I am not calling refresh after any action but when ever I click on the icon just want to refresh the component

Answer (score 0):

I had the same requirement to self refresh a component. The details are discussed below briefly. The approach is based on the idea suggested by Fabien above.

Steps to Self Refresh a Component

SCENARIO :: The scenario is to create a Contact record via LDS. I have a Lightning Card with the Contact Input Fields. Once the Contact is saved I wanted to refresh the Component to show blank input Fields ready to create next 
Contact record.

Step 01 :: Create an Event

```
<aura:event type="COMPONENT" description="Self Refresh" />
```

Step 02 :: Register and Handle the event by calling appropriate JS method (Component)

```
<!-- Register and handle the Refresh Event to refresh the current component -->
<aura:registerEvent name="selfRefreshEvt" type="c:compSelfRefresh" />

<!-- Now handle the selfRefreshEvt by calling createCntCreateTempl which is the same method called on init to initialize a Contact Obj  -->
<aura:handler name="selfRefreshEvt" event="c:compSelfRefresh" action="{!c.createCntCreateTempl}" />
```

Step 03 :: Fire the Event (Controller.js)

```
// Fire selfRefreshComp Evt (start)
// Get the component event by using the name value from aura:registerEvent

    var selfRefreshEvent = component.getEvent("selfRefreshEvt");              
    selfRefreshEvent.fire(); 

// Fire selfRefreshComp Evt (end)
```