# Refresh Single Lightning Component, Not Entire Page

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have a page that contains two lightning components. One is a calendar, the other is a list view.

On the calendar lightning component, a user will click, a hidden modal will be displayed so the user can create a record. Upon save success, I want *just the calendar component* to refresh. Not the entire page.

I've tried using $A.get('e.force:refreshView').fire(); on the callback in the calendar component. The result is both components refreshing. Same result when I create and fire a refresh event in the calendar component.

I can't seem to find much documentation in regards to refreshing single components on a page. Any ideas?

Comment: When do you want to refresh the component, when you click a button from parent component or on the same component?

Comment: Could you post your code here?

Comment: The below link may help :: [How to refresh the specific Lightning component not the lightning page](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/174741/how-to-refresh-the-specific-lightning-component-not-the-lightning-page/286844#286844)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a custom lightning Component, Call the doinit() method after every action done, place a spinner within that time of getting records from the server.

Comment: I actually tried this the first time around, and am not getting the page to refresh at all. (Can confirm the doInit IS re-rerunning with log statements, but page is not refreshing).