# Refresh all aura attributes(entire component) based on an action

Tags: lightning-aura-components, aura, javascript-controller

I have a aura component that opens when we click on a button.
Inside this component, when I do a certain action, the entire component needs to reload, basically I want all the aura:attributes to be rest to default.

currently, the code looks something like this in the controller.js:
someName function gets called based on an action in the component.

```
someName : function(component){

var anAttribute = component.get("v.anAttribute");
if(anAttribute == true){
    //This is where I need the refresh action to be fired
  }
}
```

Comment: See this answer : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/174741/how-to-refresh-the-specific-lightning-component-not-the-lightning-page